# Many new folders in home directory after open jdk installation

Tags: command-line, jdk, openjdk

I installed open openjre using terminal`sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre` because I wanted to run a script file in terminal which requires jre, after installation some new folders came up in **home directory** [image: this how it looks like now] I want to know from where does these folders came from and how can I remove them?

Answer (score 1):

They are hidden folders. Don't remove them - just press Ctrl+H to hide them again.

Answer (score 0):

> some new folders came up in home directory

You mean .Adobe, .codeblocks, .java .macromedia?

> I want to know from where does these folders came from

Besides the normal (hidden) folders I see a bunch from Adobe (listed above) so those are installed by the installation of JDK.

> and how can I remove them?

- Why the need to remove them?
- If you really want to: purge JDK.
- Press control-H if you do not want to see these folders.